# CSS positioning horizontally

Tags: html, css

Although I don't have any code in particular, this is just something I was wondering.

Under the default  (position:static)  attribute, the contents appear by HTML flow, and this flow occurs vertically. Is it possible to make it occur horizontally? To clarify, lets say you have 2 images, normally it would display image 1 above image 2 (vertical), is there a way to make it horizontal WITHOUT doing the (position:relative) to parent and (position:absolute) to child?

Comment: `img` is an inline element, so as long as your image widths, combined, were less than the width of the viewport, they would already show side by side...

Comment: The flow, by the way, occurs vertically for block elements, and horizontally for inline elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add flex to your parent container, nowrap is default behaviour I just put it there for clairity.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.child {
  flex-basis: 50rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" class="child" />
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" class="child" />
</div>
```

Comment: There's no reason to go through all of the trouble with the extra HTML and CSS. `img` is inline and will display side by side by default.

Comment: @HereticMonkey not really and yes, one can only assume that images will have a container and not be placed directly in the body, this solution would also cover all types of elements. If horizontal scroll is wanted this solution covers that.